# Why is endianess not relevant for single bytes?

Tags: cpu

If I am flipping endianess of the value `0xA1A2A3A4` I will result in `0xA4A3A2A1`.
But I don't understand why the rule seems to stop at the per-byte level. Ie if I had a single byte `0xA1` I can't flip it. It is the same for a big and little machine.

Yet if we look at `0xA1` in binary it is `10100001` and we could flip that to `01011110` but that is `0x5E`. So, I don't understand. Is endianess not about binary? Is it at the registry level (or whatever we want to call the level above binary, per-byte level)? If we have a 32 bit CPU is it actually still 8 bit registers just grouped into 4? If we operate on a single byte of 8 bits, why doesn't endianess matter?

Comment: Endianess concerns **bytes**, not the **bits** inside the bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the endianess is related to the memory addresses, not to the content itself.

Endianess is the order of the bytes in the computer memory.